# Prove that there exists two roots in $[-1,1]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

If we have:

$a>0,a+b+c \ge 0,a-b+c \ge 0,a-c \ge 0,b^2-4ac \ge 0$

Then Prove that there exists two roots in $[-1,1]$.

We have $f(1),f(-1) \ge 0$ so if we could prove there is a number $c$ that $f(c)<0$ and $-1<c<1$ we are done but I can't do that.

**Edit**:$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

**Edit 2** I made a typo and corrected it now.Now using answer of @George Law It only remains to check the case $\Delta =0$ which is likely to cause problem with $a-c \ge o$ because we didn't use it.

Comment: A root of what? What is $f$?

Comment: From his quetion I think It should be $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

Comment: @M.Winter edited.

Comment: this is a convex function, the best root for you to follow is to see where is its minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $b^2-4ac\ge 0$ implies there are two roots (distinct or repetitive).

Assume the two roots are $x_1$ and $x_2$. Then:
$$a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=ax^2+(\underbrace{-ax_1-ax_2}_{b})x+\underbrace{ax_1x_2}_{c}=0.$$
The given conditions:
$$\begin{cases}a+b+c\ge 0 \\ a-b+c\ge 0 \\
a-c\ge 0 \end{cases} \Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}a-ax_1-ax_2+ax_1x_2\ge 0 \\ a+ax_1+ax_2+ax_1x_2\ge 0 \\ a-ax_1x_2\ge 0 \end{cases} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}(1-x_1)(1-x_2)\ge 0 \\ (1+x_1)(1+x_2)\ge 0 \\ x_1x_2\le 1\end{cases}$$

Thus $x_1,x_2\in[-1,1]$, otherwise the system of the three inequalities do not hold true.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try $f\left(-\frac b{2a}\right)$.

Comment: That will give the minimum $\frac{-\Delta }{4a}$ which can be zero how do you prove it is non zero?

Comment: If it is zero then $x=-\frac b{2a}$ is a root!

Comment: Sorry I made a typo it's two roots.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Then, apart from the observations made by you observe that,
$$ f'(1)=2a+b\geq2a-a-c=a-c\geq0$$
and
$$ f'(-1)=b-2a\leq a+c-2a=c-a\leq0$$
$f'(1)$ is positive and $f'(-1)$ is negative hence there must be some $c$ with $f'(c)=0$. Since $b^2-4ac\geq0$ you infer that the roots of the quadratic equation lie in the interval.