# Prove that the roots are real and that they belong to the interval $-1 \le x \le 1$

Tags: inequality

The polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ satisfies: $a>0, a+b+c \ge 0, a-b+c \ge 0, a-c \ge 0$ and $b^2-4ac \ge 0$. Prove that the roots are real and that they belong to the interval $-1 \le x \le 1$

I started proving it this way:
Here it is stated $b^2 - 4ac \ge 0$, therefore, the roots are real.

Now the roots are: $ -\frac{b}{2a} \pm \frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

From the inequalities $a-b+c \ge 0$ and $a-c\ge0$, we get $2a\ge b$
Therefore, $-\frac{b}{2a}\ge-1$ and $b \ge a \Rightarrow b > 0$
Now I can see the other part of the root can be also shown to be greater than or equal 1. For that, I'll have to prove $4a^2\ge b^2-4ac$
Squaring both sides of  $2a\ge b$, I get $4a^2\ge b^2$
And from inequality $a-c \ge 0$ we get $a \ge c \Rightarrow 4a^2 \ge 4ac$
I don't know how to proceed from here. Is this the correct approach to prove it? If not, then how should I prove the statement?

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Let the polynomial you are given be $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. What can you say about the value of $p(x)$ at the ends of the interval of interest?

$4ap(x)=(2ax+b)^2-(b^2-4ac)$ and has the same sign as $p(x)$ because $a\gt 0$. There is clearly a minimum value when $x=-\frac {b}{2a}$ and $4ap(-\frac {b}{2a})$ is given as negative.

If the roots both lie in the interval then the minimum value will also lie in that interval ie $-1\le -\frac {b}{2a}\le 1$ or  $-2a\le -b \le 2a$ (noting again that $a\gt 0$). And you are nearly done on that.

If you sketch a graph putting these pieces together you will see that this is sufficient, and should be able to express that in suitably accurate mathematical language.

Notice how these observations use each of the pieces of information you are given. Locating roots when you have partial information sometimes relies on identifying where a function is known to be positive/negative.

Answer (score 1):

Note 1: $f(1)=a+b+c\ge 0, f(-1)=a-b+c\ge 0$.

Note 2: $b^2-4ac\ge 0$ implies there are two different or identical real roots.

Note 3:
$$(a+b+c \ge 0) + (a-c \ge 0) \Rightarrow 2a+b\ge 0 \Rightarrow -b\le 2a\\
(a-b+c \ge 0) + (a-c \ge 0) \Rightarrow 2a-b\ge 0 \Rightarrow -b\ge -2a \ \ \ \ \\
-2a\le -b\le 2a \stackrel{a>0}{\iff} -1\le -\frac{b}{2a}\le 1.$$
From the three notes above it follows the roots are in $[-1,1]$. (Why?)

Comment: Seems that you answered the same question before: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2385538/42969 :)

Comment: @MartinR, surprisingly, I had not even known it until you brought it up. However, I used different method. Moreover, the answers given in this thread only enrich the problem solution.

Comment: I have tried and I don't get it why the three notes would imply the roots are in [-1,1]. Does the first note imply 1 and -1 are two roots? Does the second note only imply the roots are real, or does it imply something more? I understand in the third note, $-\frac{b}{2b}$ are in the interval [-1,1]. But what about the $\pm \frac{\sqrt{b^2}-4ac}{2a}$ part of the roots?
Does it mean I need further studies in quadratic equations?

Comment: Think of a parabola. First note implies the two points are in quarters 1 and 2, respectively. The second note implies the parabola intersects or touches the $x$-axis. And the third note implies the parabola turns between $-1$ and $1$. Also, remember, the branches of the parabola open up. So, where will be the intersection (or touching) points of the parabola?

Comment: This is a really nice explanation. What does it mean the parabola turns? Does it mean the place it enters the x-axis and the place it leaves the x-axis, meaning the intersection points? Or does it mean the minimum of the parabola? Does $-1\le -\frac{b}{2a}\le 1$ imply the roots turn in [-1,1] because $-\frac{b}{2a}$ is the point where the parabola is the minimum? Thank you for being patient with the questions.

Comment: Yes, turning point (vertex) of parabola is the min (or max) point. When its branches open up, the turning point is minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=0$. As $b^2\ge4ac$ this has two real roots, so $f(x)=a(x-r)(x-s)$ where $r$, $s$ are real. You are given $f(1)\ge0$ and $f(-1)\ge0$. As $f(x)$ is negative between $x=r$ and $x=s$ then $r$ and $s$ are both in one of the three intervals $[-1,1]$, $[1,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,-1]$. The first case is the one we seek. In the second case $c=ars\ge a$ so for $a-c\ge0$ we need $r=s=1$. The third case is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$.

From $b^2-4ac\ge 0$, it follows that $f$ has two real roots, possibly repeated.

From $a-b+c\ge 0$, we get  $f(-1) \ge 0$.

From $a+b+c\ge 0$, we get  $f(1) \ge 0$.

If $f(p) < 0$ for some $p\in (-1,1)$, then by the Intermediate Value Theorem, $f$ must have a zero in the interval $[-1,p)$ and a zero in the interval  $(p,1]$, and we're done.

Thus, assume $f$ is nonnegative on $[-1,1]$.

In particular, we have $f(0)=c\ge 0$.

Let the roots of $f$ be $r,s$, with $r\le s$.

From Vieta's formulas, we get $rs={\large{\frac{c}{a}}}$, hence from

- $a > 0$$\\[4pt]$

  $c \ge 0$$\\[4pt]$

  $c \le a$

we get $0\le rs\le 1$.

First suppose $r=s$.

Then from $rs\le 1$, we get $r^2\le 1$, hence $-1\le r\le 1$, so $r,s\in [-1,1]$, and we're done.

Next suppose $r < s$.

Since $a > 0$ and $r < s$, it follows that $f(x) < 0$ for $r < x < s$.

Since $a > 0$, it follows that $f$ has minimum value $f(h)$, where $h=-{\large{\frac{b}{2a}}}={\large{\frac{r+s}{2}}}$.

From $r < s$ and $h={\large{\frac{r+s}{2}}}$, we get $r < h < s$, hence $f(h) < 0$.

As you showed, we must have $h\ge -1$.

Hence, since $h\ge -1$, and $f$ is nonnegative on $[-1,1]$, we must have $h > 1$.

Then from $h < s$, we get $s > 1$, hence from $0\le rs \le 1$, we get $r < 1$.

But now we have $r < 1 < s$, and $f(1)\ge 0$, contradiction, since $f(x) < 0$ for $r < x < s$.

This completes the proof.